# Get Elements of an array in Excel-Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to get the elements of an array in my following code.

```
 Public SetDeviceInfo(ByVal TLPTestVoltage As String, ByVal rng As Range = Nothing)

        TLPTestVoltage = rng.Cells(7) 'Value passed is 7-50-21
        Dim TLPTV As String
        Dim LArray() As String 'Dim for output array
        LArray = Split(TLPTestVoltage, "-") 'split on basis of ":" char
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(TLPTestVoltage) = True Then
           TLPTV = LArray(1)
        End If
        LogInfo "Set TLPTestVoltage: " & TLPTestVoltage  
        LogInfo "TLPTV:" & TLPTV

 End Sub
```

The o/p for the above code is:

Set TLPTestVoltage: 7-50-21

TLPTV:

Can anyone explain what's wrong in getting the elements of the array from the above code. The output is nil. I din't error from my Vba too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(TLPTestVoltage)` will always be false, because `TLPTestVoltage` is a string.  If you set a breakpoint on the line inside that if statement, you'll see that the breakpoint is never reached.  You'll have to rethink what you're trying to do with that if statement.  Since I don't know what your application's needs are, I'm not sure what specifically to suggest.

Comment: My bad. Din notice that I'm checking for IsNumber. It should actually be IsText. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: @Binga Happens to everyone, glad I could help!